# Laravel 5.4 back() with input and error data does not work with catch all route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a catchall route configured in laravel like below:

```
    // catch all
    Route::get('{catchall}', [
        'uses' => 'MyGenericController@index'
    ])->where('catchall', '(.*)');

    Route::put('{catchall}', [
        'uses' => 'MyGenericController@update'
    ])->where('catchall', '(.*)');
```

And in the MyGenericController I am redirecting back in the update() action if something went wrong. And then I am checking for the values in request object in the index action/method as below:

```
class MyGenericController extends MyBaseController {

  public function index($paramNameAtTheEndOfUrl) {
     // Check if any data exist in Request because of failure from update
    \Log::info( " data = " . print_r(request()->all(), true) );
  } // index

  public function update((Request $request) {

     try {
         ...
        // Do somethings
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
       return back()->withInput($request->all())->withErrors([$e->getMessage()]);
     }
  } // Update

}
```

> Now what I am observing is that the index method is not receiving the
>   request object data when I get exception in update and I redirect
>   back.

So as per my understanding, if I am doing a **back()** call in **update()** method/action using **withInput(request()->all())** and **withError(...)**, I should be expecting the old values in my **index()** action.

But I see empty request ( no input data passed back ) in the index() method.

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: When you're using `back()->withInput()`, you get the input with `old()` helper. `request()->all()` in a GET method will return GET parameters.

Comment: OK. So how do I pass the request data from my update method (which uses PUT) to the index method (that uses GET) ? Should I use session storage with some flag to handle this situation (I will have to store the old or original data in session also) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get old input (`->old()` instead of `->all()`):

```
\Log::info( " data = " . print_r(request()->old(), true) );
```